# Error for drawable in android fragment in tabbed Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using Drawable in for button in fragment of tabbed activity in android studio. But it gives error and app crashes while returning the view. Without using drawable it works fine.
**My code for xml of fragment for button [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNcw8.png).**

**The code for java where the logcat gives error is at returning view in java fragment using inflater and it is following**.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class tab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
    }
}
```

**Error for the code in logcat is also folowing after app crashes**

> 06-28 04:36:00.823 6880-6880/com.example.tutor1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.tutor1, PID: 6880
>       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #69: Error inflating class Button
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>           at com.example.tutor1.tab1.onCreateView(tab1.java:18)
>           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)

**Layout file for the respective tab is here**:
[image: layout file for fragment]

[image: layout file]

Comment: Please rename your drawable name

Comment: Drawable name should not include number

Comment: Have you got it?

Comment: is it a vector drawable?

Comment: i renamed it but still donot works. the app crashes

Comment: no its not vector

Comment: If you have not yet resolved this issue, please provide a screenshot of your file structure containing the image that you want to set as the background.

Comment: Please share the contents of your drawable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had copes the drawable file from another project..it didnotworked. but after creating my own drawable file from scratch. it worked and now going fine.

Answer (score 0):

Drawable does not support name with the number. So please rename the drawable name as button_design_one

Comment: Drawable name can contain number but it can not start with number.

Comment: I had changed it but it still doesnot work. It gives error in line 18 where inflater returns the view inside java code of fragment

Comment: i had edited the post with necessary details.please review it. it also contains the code

Comment: I couldn't find any issues in the code given. it is showing an error in inflating Button. Can you show the top portion of layout?

Comment: please check the upper portion of layout in the edited post

Comment: Can you check drawable file is inside the drawable folder? not drawable-v24

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the name of drawable resource with number at the end and it wont crash. Please check your background file if its a vector or its format. And there is no issue in your code.

Comment: which background file?

Answer (score 0):

check your drawable background image.

Comment: there is no background image

Comment: what is button_design? is it vector or custom drawable.

Comment: Instead of providing two answers, edit your answer and provide what you have here in it.